# jQuery Ajax PHP Better Solution

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I need a better solution then this, I'm using `<span id="<?php echo $row['art_id']" name="<?php echo $row['art_featured']"></span>` to get the values from fields from my database so I could send them through jQuery Ajax, but there has to be a better way to use the values from my database and storing them in a jQuery VAR then this, any suggestions would be great thanks in advance!

jQuery

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".star").click(function(){

        var art_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var art_featured = $(this).attr('name');

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {art_id:art_id,art_featured:art_featured},
        url: "ajax-feature.php",
        success: function(data){
            if(data != false) {

            } 
            else {

            }  
        }
        });

    });
```

});

PHP

```
    <section class="row">
<?php
$sql_categories = "SELECT art_id, art_featured FROM app_articles"; 

    if($result = query($sql_categories)){
        $list = array();

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            array_push($list, $data);
        }

        foreach($list as $i => $row){ 
        ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column one">
                     <span id="<?php echo $row['art_id']; ?>" class="icon-small star"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "FAIL";
    }
?>
</section>
```

So would I be able to use the data-object thing with the ajax `data:` ?

Comment: You could try inputs of type "hidden"

Comment: Is <span/> a list of buttons?

Comment: @MarCejas its in a div  <div class="column one"><span id="<?php echo $row['art_id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $row['art_featured'];?>" class="icon-small star"></span></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer, using something like this:

```
<span 
     data-object='{"art_id":<?=$row['art_id']?>,
                  "art_featured":"<?=$row['art_featured']?>"}'
     onclick="ajaxFunction($(this))"
>
</span>

function ajaxFunction(o){
      var data = o.data('object');
      /* you can send:
       * data.art_id
       * data.art_featured
       */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M4AFQ/1/

**Update for follow-up question:**

```
$(".star").click(function(){
      var data = $(this).data('object');
      /* you can send:
       * data.art_id
       * data.art_featured
       */
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, thats very interesting but I'm getting o.data is not a function

Comment: Please check out the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Ok, don't hesitate to ask if you have questions.

Comment: Sorry just one question, is it possible to use jQuery .click() with this so I can just target a class instead on having the onclick="" ?

Comment: Thank you very much, your my savor ahah!